# How to clear Button Controls from a Form

Tags: c#, winforms

My form is blank except for a Menu Strip at the top for New Game and Exit. When the form loads, it is populated with a grid of buttons whose dimensions are read from an App.config file. What is the best way to clear all of the buttons that have been placed on the form for a new game?

```
this.Controls.Clear();
```

The above doesn't work because it deletes the Menu Strip at the top of the Form as well and it only lets me call it from the Form. I also have a function that I run within the Gameboard class for the program

```
    public void ClearButtons()
    {

        for (int q = 0; q < buttonArray.Length; q++)
        {
            buttonArray[q].Text = "";
            buttonArray[q].Enabled = true;
            buttonArray[q].BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        }
    }
```

But there has to be a better way to do this, if I could just re-load the form, it would re-populate it with the buttons needed but I can't seem to figure that out, especially from my Gameboard class. Thanks all.

Comment: Winforms? Webforms? WPF?

Comment: Windows Forms Project in VS 2012

Answer (score 2):

1) Instead of clear you can use following code which will remove all buttons:

```
  public void ClearButtons()
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
       if (Controls[i] is Button)
       {
         Controls.RemoveAt(i);
         i--;
       }
    }
  }
```

2) If you want to call this code from another class, you must pass the instance of your form to it, for example as constructor parameter

3) Create `public void MyInits()` function and move the code from `Form1_Load` there. Then just call it from `Form1_Load`

4) Edit constructor to

```
public Gameboard(int numberofButtons, Form1 frm)
```

and pass `this` then instantiating it. Than call `frm.MyInits();` in the constructor

Comment: What about re-populating the form with the buttons afterwards? Look at the code below that I posted for how my form is populated

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this.Controls.Clear

You could do loop through this.Controls, and test to see if it was a Button and then remove it.

A better way though, would be to create a container, panel or some such, and create your buttons inside that and use

```
this.Controls.Remove(myPanel);
myPanel.Dispose();
```

Comment: I tried your code but its not removing the panel on the form. That is still there as it was created.

Comment: Based on the code you've just posted, don't do this. I thought you were creating and adding the buttons on the fly. What you are doing, creating them, then adding or removing on the fly.

Comment: Still nothing happening. I am creating the `buttons` like this `Button SampleButton = new Button()` and then after modifying some attributes i use this `panel1.Controls.Add(SampleButton)`.

Comment: Based on your other post, and that the GameBoard instance owns the buttons, myPanel.Controls.Clear(), might do the job. Given that Gamboard does own them though, I'd make it a UserControl and put this issue and many more potential ones to bed.

Answer (score 0):

So this is my Gameboard constructor and Ill show you how the Form calls it to populate with buttons at the bottom.

```
public Gameboard(int numberofButtons) //Constructor method that is referencing the App.config for the dimensions value to make the board
    {
        if (numberofButtons <= 0) 
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid Grid"); //throws an exception for an invalid grid size if dimensions is equal to or less than zero

        buttonArray = new Button[numberofButtons]; //creating an array the size of numberofButtons which is the dimensions value from App.config
        Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", 36.0f); //creates an instance of the Font class
        int sqrtY = (int) Math.Sqrt(numberofButtons);
        int z = 0; //Counter for array

        //Create the buttons for the form
        //Adds the buttons to the form first with null values then changes the .Text to ""
        for (int x = 0; x < sqrtY; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < sqrtY; y++)
            {
                buttonArray[z] = new Button();
                buttonArray[z].Font = font;
                buttonArray[z].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 100);
                buttonArray[z].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100*y, 100*x);
                buttonArray[z].Click += new EventHandler(button_click);
                z++; 
            }
        }//At the end of this loop, buttonArray contains a number of buttons equal to Dimensions all of which have a .Text property of ""
    }
```

So here is when the Form loads:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Read the App.Config file to get the dimensions of the grid
            int dimensions = Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dimensions"]);

            //Create the gameboard object with all the buttons needed
            Gameboard gb = new Gameboard(dimensions); //Calls the Gameboad constructor method

            //Add buttons to the form
            for (int x = 0; x < gb.buttonArray.Length; x++)
            {
                this.Controls.Add(gb.buttonArray[x]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

After I clear the buttons off the Form, what do I need to call to re-run the Form_Load so that it re-populates??

Comment: Ahhh. Have a look at UserControl. You could wrap all this up in your own user component. and not need all this add and remove stuff.

Answer (score -1):

```
int n = 0;
while (n < number)
{
    btnArray[n].Name = "" + (n + 1);
    tablePanel.Controls.Remove(btnArray[n]);
    n++;
}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should always contain an explanation.